# Change the length of ContextPre and ContextPost in Quanteda KWIC

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

Is there a way to increase the number of words appearing before and after the keyword in Quanteda kwic function?

I've tried by changing the numeric value in:

```
options(width = 200)
```

but it didn't work. 
@KenBenoit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`options(width)` affects the number of text columns displayed by the R interpreter. You want the `window` argument to `kwic()`:

```
>  kwic(data_corpus_inaugural, "war against")
                                               contextPre     keyword                         contextPost
 [1857-Buchanan, 2933:2934] advantage of the fortune of [ war against ] a sister republic, we
 [1901-McKinley, 2284:2285]         . We are not waging [ war against ] the inhabitants of the Philippine
 [1901-McKinley, 2299:2300]  portion of them are making [ war against ] the United States. By
 [1901-McKinley, 2413:2414]    used when those who make [ war against ] us shall make it no
[1933-Roosevelt, 1851:1852]   Executive power to wage a [ war against ] the emergency, as great
>  kwic(data_corpus_inaugural, "war against", window=7)
                                                       contextPre     keyword                                  contextPost
 [1857-Buchanan, 2933:2934] to take advantage of the fortune of [ war against ] a sister republic, we purchased these
 [1901-McKinley, 2284:2285]      be deceived. We are not waging [ war against ] the inhabitants of the Philippine Islands.
 [1901-McKinley, 2299:2300]      . A portion of them are making [ war against ] the United States. By far the
 [1901-McKinley, 2413:2414]  needed or used when those who make [ war against ] us shall make it no more.
[1933-Roosevelt, 1851:1852]   - broad Executive power to wage a [ war against ] the emergency, as great as the
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AdamObeng! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Do you possibly know how to turn the output of kwic into a corpus for further analysis?  For example, in inaugCorpus, I want to do sentiment analysis based on the 10 sentences before and after the word "war against".  The only way I know is to create a corpus of those text and create a doc frequency matrix (dfm) based on a dictionary, etc.

Comment: @DebNa I think so, but you should ask that as a new question (and tag me in it) so that it's easier for other people to find